# openid-configuration: DNS Fail

Tags: sitecore-cli

We are using Sitecore 10.3. For the local setup we are using docker. The local setup works fine(cm, id and frontend site) except logging in to Sitecore using Sitecore CLI. It is failing with below error.

```
Error connecting to https://id.abc.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration: DNS Fail
```

I am using the below command to login into Sitecore via Sitecore cli.

```
dotnet sitecore login --authority https://id.abc.localhost
--cm https://cm.abc.localhost --allow-write true
```

It was working fine before, suddenly it stopped working without making any changes.
I have checked the host file and I can see an entry for `id.abc.localhost` and `cm.abc.localhost`.
When I browse the `https://id.abc.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration`, I see a JSON result.
Also successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache using `ipconfig/flushdns`.

Still the issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by disabling the firewall. The firewall was blocking the access. It can be blocked either by the default system firewall or any specialised software like cisco secure client.